# set_at called multiple times in Google Maps V3 API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
poly.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);

function addLatLng(event) {

    var path = poly.getPath();

    // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
    // and it will automatically appear
    path.push(event.latLng);

    // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: '#' + path.getLength(),
        map: map,
        dragable: false,
        clickable: true,
        name: name,
        raiseOnDrag: false,
    });

    //This event is fired when setAt() is called. The event passes the index that was passed to setAt() and the element that was previously in the array at that index.
    google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function(index,oldWP) {                   
        //called when editing the path
        //we need to remove the (current) marker and add a new one at the position

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function(index) {
        //when insert happens not at the end of the path but somewhere in the middle
        //We need to completely rerender all makers 

    });
}
```

Google documentation: **This event is fired when setAt() is called. The event passes the index that was passed to setAt() and the element that was previously in the array at that index.**

However this event is called x times (where x is the # elem of the path).

Anybody know why this is and if this can be prevented (asside from keeping a counter in memory).

Comment: What is triggering the event(path.push() will not do it, so there must be something else what is modifying the path)

Comment: I've edited the code; so addLatLng is called for each click; which should happen; but puting the event listeners outside the addLatLng function doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: declare path outside of the function, and you'll be able to add the listeners outside of the function

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is that you are adding new listeners to the path for each time the path changes. What you want to do is to only add the listeners once. I think this should do the trick:

```
poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
poly.setMap(map);
var path = poly.getPath();

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);

function addLatLng(event) {

    // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
    // and it will automatically appear
    path.push(event.latLng);

    // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: '#' + path.getLength(),
        map: map,
        dragable: false,
        clickable: true,
        name: name,
        raiseOnDrag: false,
    });
}

 //This event is fired when setAt() is called. The event passes the index that was passed to setAt() and the element that was previously in the array at that index.
google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function(index,oldWP) {                   
    //called when editing the path
    //we need to remove the (current) marker and add a new one at the position

});

google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function(index) {
    //when insert happens not at the end of the path but somewhere in the middle
    //We need to completely rerender all makers 

});
```